# Mask RCNN is not able to identify objects too close to each other

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I have been trying to train a Mask RCNN model to identify individual poker chips in a stack. No matter what property I change, the end results look like the following image. I was guessing the issue is that the objects are too close to each other for the proper detection. Is there any alternative model or property of mask RCCN or my training model I could possibly try to change?

[Here is an image of the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rY6nj.jpg)

[Here is an example of my training data annotations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIsg3.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Mask RCNN makes bounding box predictions and instance segmentation of an object in each of them. As mentioned [here](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN#differences-from-the-official-paper),

> Some datasets provide bounding boxes and some provide masks only. To support training on multiple datasets we opted to ignore the bounding boxes that come with the dataset and generate them on the fly instead.

So using that [repo](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN#differences-from-the-official-paper) your labeled data is correct (earlier I wrote that the labelling is wrong).

Your task does not seem too difficult for Mask-RCNN, so I guess you should use larger dataset + data augmentations to get better results.

Comment: I see what you're saying but I'm not sure what would be wrong with my labeling. Here is an example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIsg3.jpg Is there a way to define an object and its interior instances (parts of the object) in the labeling?